# store and add new line + date stamp to document from java app

Tags: java, document

Hello i have coded an application to write something from a TextArea into a text document but the problem is,he does write it,but it dosen't store it and when i open it again,to write more in the same text document(or create a new document).
How could i do that ?
And a aditional information that i would require is how can i add date stamp  alonside the text i enter in text document?
Here is my code :

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Write extends JFrame {
    JTextArea text;

    public Write() {
        this.setTitle("Writerz!");
        setSize(400, 200);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocation(370, 150);
        setLayout(null);

        JLabel lbltitlu = new JLabel("Insert your text here");
        lbltitlu.setBounds(85, 5, 120, 25);
        this.add(lbltitlu);

        final JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
        text.setSize(199, 199);
        text.setBounds(85, 65, 120, 25);
        add(text);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Add text");
        btn.setSize(99, 99);
        btn.setBounds(125, 125, 120, 25);
        add(btn);

        ActionListener listenerbtn = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO auto- generated method
                String actionbtn = arg0.getActionCommand();

                if (actionbtn.equals("Add text")) {
                    Adauga(text.getText());


                }
            }
        };
        btn.addActionListener(listenerbtn);
    }

    public void Adauga(String text) {
        String filename = "test.txt";

        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(filename);
            writer.write(text);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.err.println("Save oops");
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    System.err.println("Error closing writer");
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace your Adauga method with this code:

```
public void Adauga(String text) {
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    BufferedWriter bufferWritter = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file, true);
        bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write("Hello: " + " --- " + ts + "\r\n");
        bufferWritter.close();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.err.println("Save oops");
    } finally {
        if (bufferWritter != null) {
            try {
                bufferWritter.close();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.err.println("Error closing writer");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you need to import packages java.sql.Timestamp and java.util.Date

Comment: the code you shown me it dosen't work,  bufferWritter.write(text+" --- "+ts);
        bufferWritter.close(); says it cannot be rezolved as symbol and file.getame says the same? what is that mean?:-s (sorr i;m a noob :D )

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
out.write(text.getText());
out.close();
```

instead of using `FileWriter`.
I made a notepad in java and that's what I use. 3 lines of code and it works perfectly.
For the date, you can simply use Date(), importing `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
Date date= new Date();
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");

// Create the file if it doesn't exist
if(!file.exists()){
    file.createNewFile();
}

// With true you append
FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
bufferWritter.write(data);
bufferWritter.close();
```